# "onclick" attribute added to nested lists through javascript doesn't work when clicked in reverse order

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a show/hide list from scratch. The list works when I click from top down but bombs when I click it from down up. I'd appreciate it if someone can point out what I'm doing wrongly, thank you!

EDIT: Sorry, I just noticed that the first words are actually clickable. "Second" and "Third" expands the list but "Element" doesn't.

```js
var clickableLists = document.querySelectorAll("p:only-of-type");
for (var i = 0; i < clickableLists.length; i += 1) {
  clickableLists[i].setAttribute("onclick", "showMore(this.nextElementSibling)");
}

function showMore(selectedElement) {
  selectedElement.style.opacity = "1";
  selectedElement.style.height = "auto";
}
```

```css
ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>List Viewer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>First Element</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>One</p>
          <ul>
            <li>+ Test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Two</p>
          <ul>
            <li>+ Test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Second Element</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>One</p>
          <ul>
            <li>+ Test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Two</p>
          <ul>
            <li>+ Test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Third Element</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>One</p>
          <ul>
            <li>+ Test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Two</p>
          <ul>
            <li>+ Test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your invisible elements are overflowing their container with `height: 0` and sitting on top of the following elements, intercepting their clicks. It’s easier to see the problem without the opacity change:

```js
var clickableLists = document.querySelectorAll("p:only-of-type");

for (var i = 0; i < clickableLists.length; i += 1){
  clickableLists[i].setAttribute("onclick", "showMore(this.nextElementSibling)");
}

function showMore(selectedElement) {
  selectedElement.style.opacity = "1";
  selectedElement.style.height = "auto";
}
```

```css
ul {
  height: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>First Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Second Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Third Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could add `overflow: hidden` instead to ensure nothing overflows the `<ul>`s with `height: 0`, but it’s even easier to just set `display: none`, which will remove an element from the flow entirely.

It’s also best practice not to represent JavaScript as a string inside JavaScript. You can assign a function directly to an element’s `onclick` property:

```
clickableLists[i].onclick = function () {
  showMore(this.nextElementSibling);
};
```

```js
var clickableLists = document.querySelectorAll("p:only-of-type");

for (var i = 0; i < clickableLists.length; i += 1){
  clickableLists[i].onclick = function () {
    showMore(this.nextElementSibling);
  };
}

function showMore(selectedElement) {
  selectedElement.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>First Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Second Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Third Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried commenting out the opacity, totally did not expect to see that. Learned my lesson. Thank you Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

Use "visibility: hidden;" instead of "opacity: 0;"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>List Viewer</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    ul {
      visibility: hidden;
      height: 0;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <p>First Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Second Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Third Element</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>One</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Two</p>
        <ul>
          <li>+ Test</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clickableLists = document.querySelectorAll("p:only-of-type");
  for (var i = 0; i < clickableLists.length; i += 1){
    clickableLists[i].setAttribute("onclick", "showMore(this.nextElementSibling)");
  }
  function showMore(selectedElement) {
    selectedElement.style.visibility = "visible";
    selectedElement.style.height = "auto";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```